# How do I select a date that is 4 days ago at this time?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, timestamp

I need to query to get rows where a `timestamp` was after exactly 4 days ago this time.

For example if I run the query at 1pm on June 6, 2012 it should select rows where the date is after 1pm on June 2, 2012. How do I do this?

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE created_at < /* 4 days ago this time */;
```

Comment: Be careful that you consider the implications of what happens when the times equal exactly down to the second, a possibility in a busy system (and then a candidate to look at changing the column to timestamp).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

believe it or not, it's super-easy.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE created_at > sysdate - 4
```

Comment: +1.  You can also do `created_at < sysdate - interval '4' day`.  That's a bit more verbose but it may be clearer if you don't immediately know that subtracting a number from a date subtracts that number of days.  I much prefer it when you get into subtracting hours or minutes.

Comment: good point.  Mine is the "default", but clarity can often be better.

Comment: When I ran `SELECT sysdate - 4 FROM mytable` it did not include the time it just selected June 2, 2012 not June 2, 2012 1pm.

Comment: @Adam, It all depends on your nls settings.  Oracle dates by default go down to the second level.  Simply to_char(sysdate-4,'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') if you want to see the full date & time.